# error TS2339: Property 'scan' does not exist on type 'Observable<Message[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am following this [tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/chatbot-in-angular-with-dialogflow-api-ai/) for making chatbot with angular. I get following error:

ERROR in src/app/chat/chat-dialog/chat-dialog.component.ts(24,6): error TS2339: Property 'scan' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

I am using Angular & Angular CLI version: 6.0.3.

chat-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService, Message } from '../chat.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators';




@Component({
  selector: 'chat-dialog',
  templateUrl: './chat-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class ChatDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  messages: Observable<Message[]>;
  formValue: string;

  constructor(public chat: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // appends to array after each new message is added to feedSource
    this.messages = this.chat.conversation.asObservable()
    .scan((acc, val) => acc + val);
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.chat.converse(this.formValue);
    this.formValue = '';
  }

}
```

chat.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

// Message class for displaying messages in the component
export class Message {
  constructor(public content: string, public sentBy: string) {}
}

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {

  readonly token = environment.dialogflow.angularBot;
  readonly client = new ApiAiClient({ accessToken: this.token });

  conversation = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>([]);

  constructor() {}

  // Sends and receives messages via DialogFlow
  converse(msg: string) {
    const userMessage = new Message(msg, 'user');
    this.update(userMessage);

    return this.client.textRequest(msg)
               .then(res => {
                  const speech = res.result.fulfillment.speech;
                  const botMessage = new Message(speech, 'bot');
                  this.update(botMessage);
               });
  }



  // Adds message to source
  update(msg: Message) {
    this.conversation.next([msg]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`scan` is an Operator that needs to be piped.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.messages = this.chat.conversation.asObservable()
      .pipe(
        scan((acc, val) => acc + val)
      )
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now: ERROR in node_modules/api-ai-javascript/ts/Request/TTSRequest.ts(17,31): error TS2339: Property 'DEFAULT_TTS_HOST' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiAiConstants'.

Comment: That's a separate problem, I'd suggest you have a closer look at it and open a new question if you get stuck

Comment: Just a comment, I had error with acc + val sentence 
For fix it,  I used acc.concat(val)

Comment: If it helps, the import was incorrect in the tutorial I was following that I think was the same here. It should be ->  import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators'; instead of import 'rxjs/add/operator/scan'; It is in the comments of that tutorial as well.